# Rails Deleting SQL result from inner join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, migration

i have two tables Accounts and Details.

an account has many details.

one of the details is company size. they are ranked from 1-7. i would like to remove all accounts where the size is 6 then i would like to update the accounts so that all those that where size 7 are changed to size 6. so basically i am removing size 6 companies from the system. i am thinking about doing this in a migration.

```
class RemoveEmeAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("*****")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Update details set size = 6 where size = 7")
  end
end
```

the issue is the sql statement to delete the companies whos size is 6 i was thinking something like this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE accounts INNER JOIN details ON accounts.id=details.account.id WHERE details.size = 6")
```

but that looks funny to me. i am really new to sql statements so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this task using ActiveRecord API. You should always try to minimize the amount of plain SQL statements inside your application (for cross database compatibility).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  Account.joins(:details).where(:size => 6).delete_all
  Account.joins(:details).where(:size => 7).update_all(:size => 6)
end
```

Comment: you sir should be knighted! wow that is a very ruby way of solving the  problem!

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
DELETE accounts 
from details INNER JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = details.account_id
WHERE details.size = 6
```

However, keep in mind that this will leave orphaned records in your details table

Answer (score 1):

Well, this SQL statement will work. Here i make an inner SELECT to get all the ids you want, and use it on the outer DELETE.

```
DELETE FROM accounts 
WHERE id IN 
(
  SELECT accounts.id FROM accounts 
  INNER JOIN details ON accounts.id = details.account_id 
  WHERE details.size = 6
)
```